# Ignoring the escapeXml="true" and displaying the human readable value

Tags: jsp

For escaping the double quotes in a `.jsp` page I have written

```
<c:out....escapeXml="true"/>
```

and the quotes are ignored. But I want to include this `.jsp` page in another `.jsp` page (the page where the `c:out` is written) and display the value. But it is displaying `&34..` something instead of `"`.

What can I do to display the original with the double quotes?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Don't double-escape.